# WordPress on OpenShift Responds "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111"

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, openshift

Attempting to make changes in my OpenShift-hosted WordPress admin, I suddenly get an error:

> "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 111"

The server was running slow prior and low on storage so I used "rhc app tidy *appname*" command to cleanup.  Result:  still no MySQL connection.

I restarted the app a few times.  Result:  still no MySQL connection.

I logged into PhpMyAdmin and got the following:

> "#2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxx.x.xxx.xxx' (111)
>
> The server is not responding."

I also tried saving the app with the "rhc snapshot-save *appname*" command to ensure I at least save my data.  This only produced an empty compressed file.

There are some suggestions on this forum for localhosts with failed server connections like mine.  Can anyone advise what else can be done with OpenShift?

Thanks.

---

Further info:  this may be an OpenShift issue as the status of my app changes without my commands.  The app is now list

Any comments from anyone on how to resolve this, if possible, is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is resolved.  It may have been a problem with the host's network.  Its network's status on Twitter and its site may not have been updated to reflect this.

Attempting to debug the local backup (snapshot) feature with "-d" appended, the last command executed was:

> rhc snapshot-save *appname* -d

It seems unlikely that the appended flag for debug reports fixed the issue.